How to prove that the Blancmange function doesent have a Bounded variation?

Given the Blancmange function
$$B(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} f_{n}(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{f_{1}(2^{n-1}x)}{2^{n-1}}.$$
where $f_{1}$,is the saw tooth function. Now a bounded variation is defined by
$$ V^{b}_{a}(f)=\sup_{P\in\mathcal{P}}\sum^{n_{P}-1}_{i=0}|f(x_{i+1})-f(x_{i})|.$$

So to prove that $B(x)$ is not a bounded variation we would need to prove that $V^{b}_{a}(f)=\infty$. But how do I compute this? I don't understand even how to begin. As I was trying to understand I came across this post, where the first answer explains why this is true. But I also didn't understand and I feel many things are just said and not proven. Any help would be amazing, thank you.

Since you asked how, rather than for an actual proof, I'll go over the usual strategy for problems of this kind.
As you noted, the total variation $V^a_b(f)$ of a function $f$ over an interval $[a,b]$ is the supremum of the variations of $f$ over each possible partition of $[a,b]$. You don't need to compute this supremum, you just need to show that no supremum exists.
A good general strategy for showing a set has no supremum is to construct a sequence in that set which diverges to $+\infty$.
Can you come up with a sequence $(P_n)$ of partitions of $[a,b]$ such that the variation over $P_n$ diverges to $+\infty$ as $n \to \infty$?
If not, a good general strategy for constructing sequences which diverge in this way is to come up with a term larger than $N$ for each $N \in \mathbb{N}$, and ensuring the sequence is monotonically increasing. Can you come up with a partition whose variation is $\geq M$ for a given $M \geq 0$?
One more hint specific to this problem: the Blancmange function is self-similar and periodic with period 1, so you can first consider partitions of $[0,1]$, then adapt your proof for general $[a,b]$.
If these hints don't help I can try to supply a proof, but I'd encourage you to try to use them first.

Thanks a lot, I will be trying these coming days, if I don't manage to do it by myself Ill comment again.

@rake after some time I came up with this solution (it took some time as I was busy, sorry). I hope this is a good solution:
Without loss of generality, we will prove this for the interval $[0,1]$ (we can do this considering the property of self-similarity in all intervals of this function). Taking the Takagi/Blancmange function
$$B(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} f_{n}(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{f_{1}(2^{n-1}x)}{2^{n-1}}.$$
its bounded variation is given by $V_{0,1}(B(x))$. Now, take a partial sum of the Takagi function, $T(x):=\sum^{k}_{n=1} f_{n}(x),$ and its bounded variation is $V_{0,1}(T(x))$.
Then notice that for $n\leq k$ we have:
$$V_{0,1}(B(x))=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}V_{0,1}(T(x))=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}V_{0,1}\bigg(\sum^{k}_{n=1} f_{n}(x)\bigg)=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sum^{k}_{n=1}V_{0,1}(f_{n}(x)).$$
First we calculate $V_{0,1}(f_{n}(x))$:
$$V_{0,1}(f_{n}(x))=V_{0,1/2}(f_{n}(x))+V_{1/2,1}(f_{n}(x))=V_{0,1/2}(2^{-n+1}f^{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}_{1}(2^{n-1 }x))+V_{1/2,1}(2^{-n+1}f^{[\frac{1}{2},1]}_{1}(2^{n-1 }(1-x)))\notag\\
    =V_{0,1/2}(x)+V_{1/2,1}(1-x).$$
Now take two partitions $\mathcal{P}_{1}$, $\mathcal{P}_{2}$ such that $0=x_{0},\dots,x_{n_{p}}=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}=y_{0},\dots,y_{n_{p}}=1$ for the intervals $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $[\frac{1}{2},1]$ respectively. With this, we calculate the bounded variation.
$$V_{0,1}(f_{n}(x))=\sup\sum^{n_{p}}_{i=1}|x_{i+1}-x_{i}|+\sup\sum^{m_{p}}_{j=1}|1-x_{j+1}-(1-x_{j})|\notag\\
    =\sup\sum^{n_{p}}_{i=1}|x_{i+1}-x_{i}|+\sup\sum^{n_{p}}_{i=1}|x_{i+1}-x_{i}|=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1.
$$
Then,
$$
    \sum^{k}_{n=1}V_{0,1}(f_{n}(x))=\sum^{k}_{n=1} 1=k.
$$
Considering the second equation,
$$
V_{0,1}(B)=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}V_{0,1}(T(x))=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sum^{k}_{n=1}V_{0,1}(f_{n}(x))=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} k=\infty.
   $$
So it is proven that the Takagi function has no bounded variation.
